# How to sum a range based on a condition?

Tags: google-sheets

I have columns with "x" and "o" and I want each "x" in a column count as 0.25 and "o" count as 0.125. How could I do this so I have the sum above each column?

In this example it would be = .25 + .125 + .25 + .125 = 0.75

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you need would be:

```
=COUNTIF(F2:F,"x")*0.25+COUNTIF(F2:F,"o")*0.125
```

**OR**

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(F2:F,"x")*0.25,COUNTIF(F2:F,"o")*0.125)
```

[image: How to sum a range based on a condition]

Functions used:

- [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)

Comment: You could probably better your title because at the moment it may be difficult to distinguish from "[Sum on condition?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/12720/117311)".